# Unable to visit pages in react router dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

I am trying to a create router. I works for home page but when i goto other page like `/btn` its not working.

The error is `Cannot GET /btn`.

I tried this with Switch and Routes components but not working.

*Code:-*

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  toggleBtn = () => {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>...Loading</div>}>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              element={<SimpleBtn toggleBtn={this.toggleBtn} />}
            />
            <Route exact path="/btn">
              <SimpleBtn2 toggleBtn={this.toggleBtn} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I almost wrote code as in [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting) but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a full [mcve]. Can we see the imports and can you share the package.json file so we can see what versions you are working with?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you, but  now my problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a server side issue. You need to add support for HTML5 Push State to the server. If youre using create-react-app this will just work out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Before I didn't use `create-react-app` but when i use it everything works fine now!